# MySQL solving for time in and time out using 1 column

Tags: mysql

Ex.

```
| ID |   LOGS   |
| 1  |  8:00:00 | --this is time in,
| 1  |  12:00:00| --this is time out,
| 2  |  20:00:00| -- time in,
| 2  |  8:00:00 | -- time out,
```

I need to solve for the hours between time in and time out. Time in and time out is found in 1 column. I'm new to MySQL and want to practice this.

Comment: [`Datediff`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) gives you a function to subtract the two dates.  What you've not defined is how you know which two dates get paired.  If we assume the ascending date in order denotes date in / out you could simulate a row number using user variables and split out the date column into two columns and then use date diff.  but until we know how you know which to dates get paired; I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: i have a column name LOG where the time_in and time_out is listed on the LOG how do i solve for the total # of hours for time in and time out if they are found on the same column??

Comment: @xQbert the parings for time in and time out is the ascending date in order..

Comment: I'm a bit confused. It sounds like the date and time are in separate columns (date for date log for time) is this accurate?  We would need to combine them into one to find the difference.  Also you've not explained the expected result.  Do you want the difference to be in hours minutes seconds or days or what? Lastly how will you know what result matches to what two records?  So layout the expected results in a table form so we have a better understanding of what you're after.  use the sample data you've provided.  What data types are date and logs as `Date` appears to be varchar since no year

Comment: @xQbert MY FAULT! Im sorry my brain is scrambling right now.. the columns are ID and LOG.. i edited my post.. so sorry..

Comment: @xQbert result shoud be in hours sorry

Comment: So logs has no date component to it?  in IDs 2 we have no way of knowing if it's 1 day or 2 days days difference then...  And again it helps us help you if we can see the expected results and the DDL (the table structure including the data types) of your table.  ID 2 just violated your comment about time in out being in ascending order without a date...  Slow down... think about the problem and make sure you provide accurate information.  We want to help; but can only do so if the problem is well defined.  So 1) Mock up expected results, 2) include table DDL so we know data types.

Comment: The problem I see right now is without a date component or an some way of knowing which log is 1st and 2nd for a given ID, we don't know which to put 1st and 2nd in the timediff/datediff calculation. Order in a database is not guaranteed.  Thus we can't rely on the order in the table to define the order you want to find the differences.  Thus logs needs a date component or we need the sequence to be defined in some other manner.

Comment: @xQbert ID = EMP_ID

Comment: What is the datatype of logs? (I'm hoping it's timestamp) so we could just use [timestampdiff](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) and the order of the lgos column asc gives us the needed order.  Right now I can't guarantee that and as such is an assumption.  Without validating that assumption; any work done would be potentially wasted.  Note: these types of problems often have situations where a person didn't log in or out accurately so the results are skewed; but that's a different issue.

Comment: @xQbert Create table test_time (EMP_ID int, LOG TIME);

Comment: Then we have a problem.  time without a date component we can't define the order of the time column and thus can't solve this problem accurately. Order of records isn't guaranteed in a table so we don't know if I should subtract 12 from 8 for ID one or 8 from 12 and vice-versa.  Also when a log wraps I don't know if it's for just 1 day or 2 or 3 or more...

Answer (score 0):

Given what I know so far...  (this is close but given some missing components this is technically unsolvable)

I don't think this is the "Correct" answer as I'm unsure of logs datatype and if it contains a date field or is just time.  if just time I'm unsure how to account for the number of days potentially different; nor how to handle the ordering of the records since order isn't guaranteed.

I'm also unsure if your data has missing pairs and how we would handle that.  Say someone didn't key in but keyed out or vice-versa.  How do we handle such situations?

What the below does is simulate the row_number functionality using user variables (@RN, @RN2) and assign a 1,2,3,4.. etc RN to each record.  Two identical data sets are generated with this row number.  I then join these datasets together on the DS1.rownumber+1 = DS2.rownumber and dataset 1's row numbers are limited to just the odd rows using a mod function.  This means that we can now subtract the date2 from date1 and get the difference.

```
SELECT ID, Col2DT, Col1DT, timestampDiff(Minute, COl2DT, Col1DT) as MinDiff
FROM (SELECT ID, Logs col1DT , @RN:=@RN+1 RN
      FROM TableName
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @RN:=0)
      ORDER BY ID, Logs Asc) Der_Tab1
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, LogsCol2DT, @RN2:=@RN2+1 RN
            FROM TableName
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT @RN2:=0)
            ORDER BY ID, Logs Asc) Der_Tab2
  on Der_tab1.ID = Der_tab2.ID
 and der_tab2.RN+1 = DerTab2.RN
WHERE mod(Der_tab1.RN,2)=1
```

- the cross join simply declares & initializes the user variables @RN & @RN2 to 0
- the order by of each subquery ensures we assign the right row number to each ID assuming log is a timestamp datatype
- the mod(der_tab1.rn,2)=1 ensures all the odd number rows are in my first der_tab1 dataset.  This means that all the even based on the join would be in the 2nd dataset (der_tab2) if we assume each ID has two log for in/out without fail then this approach would give us the two date values in 1 record we need to subtract
- the outer select then does the math and shows the ID, the two dates subtracted and the resulting difference in minutes.